# Javascript Notification API - Chrome doesn't show latest one at the top

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, notifications

I'm using Javascript Notification API and Chrome 38 version. My notification options are below:

```
var notification = new Notification(title,options);

 var notificationOptions =  {
     body: "... my datas",
     icon: "/xx/xx/notification/gift.png",
     dir : "ltr",
     requireInteraction:true
};
```

First 3 notification is oke but after 3 notification the other notifications doesn't show. When i click notification icon at system tray, i see latest ones. 
How can i show new notifications always at the top not in system tray?

[image: first 3 notification]

[image: click system tray notification icon]

[image: 4th notification is shown]